# CSS lint parsing error - expected LBRACE error

Tags: parsing, keyframe, csslint

Need some help.

When looking at my CSS in CSS lint, they constantly report a parsing error, namely 'expected LBRACE error'
Here is a screenshot of the issue: [screenshot](http://screencast.com/t/AXyy5aRmgw)

They show issue on my closing bracket. I checked my code several times, and I just can't find, what could be the issue.

What I realized if I change the key-frame prefix order, then the error shows on different lines (so not always on the closing bracket)

Here is my code, please take a look, and let me know if somebody sees an error there, and what is it, thank you in advance:

```
.flat-desktop-content {
    background: url("../images/flat-desktop-content.svg") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 360px;
    height: 290px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 9;
    -webkit-animation: flat-desktop 6s ease infinite;
       -moz-animation: flat-desktop 6s ease infinite;
            animation: flat-desktop 6s ease infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes flat-desktop {
    0% { background-position: 0 0; }
    50% { background-position: 0 -234px;}
    0% { background-position: 0 0; }
}

@-moz-keyframes flat-desktop {
    0% { background-position: 0 0; }
    50% { background-position: 0 -234px;}
    0% { background-position: 0 0; }
}

@keyframes flat-desktop {
    0% { background-position: 0 0; }
    50% { background-position: 0 -234px; }
    0% { background-position: 0 0; }
}​
```

Comment: Is it possible that your linter thinks nested curly braces are illegal? If this is the case then your linter is not good because this would make all media queries throw an error. As a test, try deleting the stops inside the keyframe (the lines that begin with n%) and see if that fixes it.  If it does, stop using that linter! This is just a stab in the dark, let me know results of test.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I tried what you proposed, and result was same..
Also I pasted in there my whole css which has a lot of media queries, and none of them were reported as an error, also I have several other animations, and all of them are ok, only this one reports an error.
Here is an example of a more complex animation, which passed without errors: [link](http://screencast.com/t/D77MXdhN) . So it is possible that it is really just a bug, not sure, but it annoys me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CSSLint is not to blame.

The problem is that an invisible character is present in your code that is causing the error. Simply set your cursor to the offending line and column and hit backspace to erase the problematic character.

If you copy this code below to csslint you will not get an error because I removed the offending character.

```
@keyframes monkey {
    0% { background-position: 0 0; }
    50% { background-position: 0 -100px; }
}
```

Comment: Yes you are right, I realized that later on, but forgot t update here.
Thank you fro the answer though!

Comment: for me it was caused by WP css code editor .

Answer (score 0):

You are using [csslint.net](http://csslint.net/) which seems to have a bug. I boiled down your example until I was left with just this short snippet of perfectly valid CSS and the error was still thrown.  Try it...

```
@keyframes monkey {
    0% { background-position: 0 0; }
    50% { background-position: 0 -100px; }
}​
```