# ASP.NET bundling not working when site is deployed

Tags: asp.net, bundling-and-minification, asp.net-bundling

I am having difficulties to understand why is this happening.

In my global.asax I have

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

There I also have these lines

```
BundleTable.Bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/content/css/bundle").
            Include("~/content/css/font-awesome.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform()).
            Include("~/content/css/bootstrap.css").
            Include("~/content/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css").
            Include("~/content/css/carousel.css").
            Include("~/content/css/narrow.css").
            Include("~/content/css/navbarLogo.css").
            Include("~/content/css/goTop.css").
            Include("~/content/css/fbKomentar.css").
            Include("~/content/css/lightbox.css"));
```

On my master page I have

```
<%: System.Web.Optimization.Styles.Render("~/content/css/bundle") %>
```

I also want to say that this site worked flawlessly when it was hosted on domain.com. Now I have transferred to mochahost.com and it is not working(don't want to start about their support either).

At the moment site is in DNS propagation so I do not have it connected to my real domain but rather the one they provided me - http://aikikai-dubrovnik.hr.wb3.my-hosting-panel.com

There you can see that the bundle is empty! Further more, if I state

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
```

I will not get my scripts 'unbundled' I will still get my rendering path

```
<link href="/content/bundle.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

This all works fine on my local machine(ofcourse!!!).

Any help/direction would be appreciated. I have read most of the tickets here on SO regarding this issue and I tried a lot of stuff people recommend but to no avail.

Comment: Works fine. If someone else reports the same thing I will look in to it.

Answer (score 0):

This usually occurs if your css files are not well formatted, put your css code to test using http://csslint.net/.

edit:
Please look at the css file:

> goTop.css

on your project with csslint, fix the error and it's probably will work.

your error:
[CSS lint parsing error - expected LBRACE error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28347983/css-lint-parsing-error-expected-lbrace-error)

Comment: I wouldn't say that's the deal otherwise it wouldn't work locally too.

Comment: I'm sorry Kobe but this doesn't work. To be honest I didn't think it would work in the first place since that *.css file is 7th in the order so it should have picked up the first sheets but it didn't. I have fallen back to using normal links to stylesheets rather than loosing anymore time with this.