# How to debug error "Expected LBRACE at [75,0] JavaFx CSS"

Tags: java, css, javafx

I don't know why I'm getting this error. I've checked each line several times.

> com.sun.javafx.css.parser.CSSParser parse
>   WARNING: CSS Error parsing file:/C:/Users/rmanassya/Desktop/BinaryNameV1.1/BinaryNamev1.1/BinaryName/bin/style.css: Expected LBRACE at [75,0]

My CSS

```
.center-text-area *.text {
-fx-text-alignment: center;
}

#top-radius{
-fx-border-radius: 50 50 0 0;
-fx-background-radius: 50 50 0 0;
}

#ipad-grey {
-fx-background-color: 
    linear-gradient(#686868 0%, #232723 25%, #373837 75%, #757575 100%),
    linear-gradient(#020b02, #3a3a3a),
    linear-gradient(#b9b9b9 0%, #c2c2c2 20%, #afafaf 80%, #c8c8c8 100%),
    linear-gradient(#f5f5f5 0%, #dbdbdb 50%, #cacaca 51%, #d7d7d7 100%);
-fx-background-insets: 0,1,4,5;
-fx-background-radius: 9,8,5,4;
-fx-padding: 15 30 15 30;
-fx-font-family: "Arial Rounded MT Bold";
-fx-font-size: 30px;
-fx-font-weight: bold;
-fx-text-fill: #333333;
-fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box , rgba(255,255,255,0.2) , 1, 0.0 , 0 
, 1);
margin: 100px;
-fx-pref-width: 300px;
}

#ipad-grey Text {
-fx-effect: dropshadow( one-pass-box , white , 0, 0.0 , 0 , 1 );
}

#shiny-orange{
-fx-background-color: 
    linear-gradient(#ffd65b, #e68400),
    linear-gradient(#ffef84, #f2ba44),
    linear-gradient(#ffea6a, #efaa22),
    linear-gradient(#ffe657 0%, #f8c202 50%, #eea10b 100%),
    linear-gradient(from 0% 0% to 15% 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.9), 
rgba(255,255,255,0));
-fx-background-radius: 30;
-fx-background-insets: 0,1,2,3,0;
-fx-text-fill: #333333;
-fx-font-weight: bold;
-fx-font-size: 30px;
-fx-padding: 10 20 10 20;
-fx-pref-width: 700px;
}

#shiny-orange-reset{
-fx-background-color: 
    linear-gradient(#ffd65b, #e68400),
    linear-gradient(#ffef84, #f2ba44),
    linear-gradient(#ffea6a, #efaa22),
    linear-gradient(#ffe657 0%, #f8c202 50%, #eea10b 100%),
    linear-gradient(from 0% 0% to 15% 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.9), 
rgba(255,255,255,0));
-fx-background-radius: 30;
-fx-background-insets: 0,1,2,3,0;
-fx-text-fill: #333333;
-fx-font-weight: bold;
-fx-font-size: 30px;
-fx-padding: 10 20 10 20;
-fx-pref-width: 300px;
}

.button-pressed:pressed{
-fx-background-color: gray;
}

#CMHlogo {
-fx-background-image: url("codinghangout_logos_green.png");
-fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;   
-fx-background-size: 270 190;
-fx-background-position: top left;
}
```

JavaFx Code

```
public class Main extends Application {

public static void main1(String[] args) {  

    if (args.length == 0) {  
        try {  
            // re-launch the app itselft with VM option passed  
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"java", "-
Dcom.sun.javafx.isEmbedded-true", "-Dcom.sun.javafx.touch=true", "-
Dcom.sun.javafx.virtualKeyboard=javafx", "-jar", "BinaryName1.jar"});  
        } catch (IOException ioe) {  
            ioe.printStackTrace();  
        }  
        System.exit(0);  
    }  

    // Run the main program with the VM option set  
    //...  
    //...  
}  

private ConversionController conversionController = new 
ConversionController();

private PopupWindow keyboard;

private final Rectangle2D visualBounds = 
Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
private final Rectangle2D bounds = Screen.getPrimary().getBounds();
private final double taskbarHeight = bounds.getHeight() - 
visualBounds.getHeight();

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    primaryStage.setTitle("Binary Name");

    Label helloLbl = new Label("Hello");
    helloLbl.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    helloLbl.setFont(Font.font("Comic Sans MS", FontWeight.BOLD, 68));
    helloLbl.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;padding: 20px;");
    helloLbl.setTextFill(Color.web("#ffffff"));



    Label myNameLbl = new Label("my name is");
    myNameLbl.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    myNameLbl.setFont(Font.font("Comic Sans MS", 48));
    myNameLbl.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;padding: 20px;");
    myNameLbl.setTextFill(Color.web("#ffffff"));

    VBox logoBox = new VBox(10);
    logoBox.setId("CMHlogo");
    logoBox.getChildren().addAll(helloLbl, myNameLbl);
    logoBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);



    TextArea nameTxtArea = new TextArea();
    nameTxtArea.setWrapText(Boolean.TRUE);
    nameTxtArea.getStyleClass().add("center-text-area");
    nameTxtArea.setFont(Font.font("Comic Sans MS", 28));
    nameTxtArea.setStyle("padding: 40px;");


    Label dummy = new Label(" ");
    dummy.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;");
    dummy.setFont(Font.font("Comic Sans MS", FontWeight.BOLD, 30));

    /**Button printBtn = new Button("PRINT");
    printBtn.setId("ipad-grey");
    printBtn.setDisable(Boolean.TRUE);*/

    Button convertBtn = new Button("Check Your Answer/Revisa Tu Respuesta");
    convertBtn.setId("shiny-orange");

    convertBtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

 nameTxtArea.setText(conversionController.getBinaryName
 (nameTxtArea.getText()));
            convertBtn.setDisable(Boolean.TRUE);
            //printBtn.setDisable(Boolean.FALSE);
            nameTxtArea.requestFocus();
        }
    });

    Button resetBtn = new Button("RESET");
    resetBtn.setId("shiny-orange-reset");
    resetBtn.getStyleClass().add("button-pressed");
    resetBtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            // Reset
            nameTxtArea.setText("");
            convertBtn.setDisable(Boolean.FALSE);
            //printBtn.setDisable(Boolean.TRUE);
            nameTxtArea.requestFocus();
        }

    });

    HBox hBox = new HBox(100);
    hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    hBox.getChildren().addAll(convertBtn); // add printBtn next to 
convertBtn, 

    VBox vBox = new VBox(10);
    vBox.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
    vBox.getChildren().addAll(logoBox, nameTxtArea, dummy, hBox, resetBtn);
    vBox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;margin: 20px;");
    vBox.setId("top-radius");
```

EDIT: I don't have line 75. The code ends at line 73. I ran it through CSSlint and didn't see an error related to this. It was working fine with the same code, but now it's not.

EDIT: I removed parts of CSS and ran the program. The program ran with CSS style applied. I completed deleted all CSS code and same thing happened. Why is it doing that? How can CSS run when there is no CSS code? I don't have any css command in my JavaFX,

Comment: Sorry, what is `*.text` in CSS file?

Comment: Which line is line 75?

Comment: The error means there is rule that is not supported by `JavaFX CSS`, so it may be what @KenY-N mentioned.

Comment: BTW, there might be [an invalid character at the end of the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28347983/css-lint-parsing-error-expected-lbrace-error).

Comment: I copied and pasted the CSS into a file and got no parse errors loading it; so some file content anomaly such as a spurious character at the end is the most likely explanation.